# pollerName() cannot accept a param like " ${id}"

Tags: scala, gatling

I want to fetch information by call an API with an unique param `doc,pollerName`. But I don't know why the pollerName() didn't accept param like "${id}",I was trying pollerName(Random.nextInt(999)),but the Random result always the same, so is there any other solutions?

```
.foreach("${idList}","id"){
    polling.pollerName("${id}").exec(some exec)
}
```

Comment: What is "polling" ? Witch type it is ? Is "pollerName" method  accept a string as argument ?

Comment: used for LOAD TEST https://gatling.io/

Comment: I don't know gatling.io but if you post method signature and stacktrace maybe we can help you

Comment: Thank you all the same，It's a bit complicated，the signature can be found @gatling.io，and  need to know some scala pragram

Comment: if u r interesting at this,https://gatling.io/docs/current/http/polling/?highlight=polling

Answer (score 0):

looking at the implementation of pollerName (in gatling 3.1), it takes a String and not an Expression[String] which would enable the use of values from the gatling session.

So I don't think gatling supports what you want

Comment: that's right,i read the gatling.http source days ago and found this out,
but the sence of my code need to keep polling for every "id" in "idList" (unknown size),
so just try to ask.
and my English isn't all that good,description of the question maybe diffficult to undersand,
thanks for the answer